# How do i install or update kdenlive with an appimage?

Tags: software-installation, updates, kdenlive, appimage

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, won't update [kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/) through the normal repositories. I have been told I can use an [appimage](https://appimage.org/), and the site gives instructions for install but it doesn't install; it just runs as a stand alone program that crashes if I try to export my video.

[image]

I have tried this as per another web site's suggestion but, no luck.

```
~/Downloads$ ./Kdenlive-17.12.0d-x86_64.AppImage install
```

I know I got an update installed on my old PC, but I can't figure out how I did it. Here's my old comment from back when i figured it out. Too bad i didn't say how i did it.

[image]

I'd be okay with the stand alone but it doesn't save my configurations and it crashes if I try to export. So all i want to do is update to version 17, or 16. And I'm told I can install an appimage but I can't find out how.

This page had instructions for install (1/2 way down the page) :
[Musescore Install](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/install-linux)
But it did not work. And i don't know if it's on me or the appimage.

Comment: @K7AAY i added ubuntu version. I don't know about gnome or kde i think both of those are things i've seen before but I've never come across a kubuntu.

Comment: Your 16.04 LTS has the Unity desktop environment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface) , which is neither Kubuntu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu (which uses the KDE desktop environment, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE) nor GNOME https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME (but _much_ closer to the latter). That's why we need to know versions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kdenlive's [Ubuntu page](http://sudo%20add-apt-repository%20ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable%20sudo%20apt-get%20update) says you *could* run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable && sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install kdenlive
```

BUT they also warn against using it with 18.10 or earlier: "*QML parts are not reliable with Qt versions below 5.11, so bionic is out of scope (18.04 LTS, basis for several derivatives)"* which explains the crashing with 16.04 LTS.

So, AppImage is a good way to go with your 16.04 LTS. After

- downloading the [AppImage](https://files.kde.org/kdenlive/release/Kdenlive-17.12.0d-x86_64.AppImage)
- move it over into ~/ then
- make it executable with `chmod a+x Kdenlive-17.12.0d-x86_64.AppImage` and launch it with
- `~/Kdenlive-17.12.0d-x86_64.AppImage`

[Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.kdenlive) ([Flatpak pre-install instructions](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu)) also offers an alternative approach, but I was unable to find v17 Kdenlive in Flatpak.

Comment: The first command seemed like it installed something but my version stayed at 15.whatever it is. The flatpak instructions gave me access to a version 19 but it did not replace my installed version, and has to be accessed through the terminal, as my kdenlive desktop shortcut still opens 15. Also I'm more interested in installing version 16 or 17, not 19. The final instructions perform no install it just runs the stand alone version.

Comment: Upon computer reboot, the version 19 did take over from my desktop short cut. But when i uninstalled the flatpak the old version was still there. So kdenlive 19 was never installed after all. Any how, as stated in the question and shown to be a possibility in the picture, i want to install the appimage.

Comment: I'm not gonna call it a bad solution, it did get a updated version running. I'm adding to the top post about something I tried without success, but it would seem installing (maybe just their appimage) is possible.

Comment: I provided the Flatpak link for the sake of completeness for those who follow; ignore its instructions, and stick with the four bulleted items containing the AppImage v17 instructions. I'd also suggest backing up all your kdenlive data and then uninstalling it before installing the v17 AppImage of Kdenlive.